# Task Scheduler does not run Excel VBA Code to send PDF as Email Attachment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, windows-task-scheduler

Here is the software/systems I am using:

Microsoft Office 2010;

Task Scheduler;

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

I am running some VBA code within an Excel file that does the following:

1. Retrieves Data from our Database via SQL/ODBC connections

2. Uploads data to a raw data table within the workbook and time stamps the workbook in a cell with the now function

3. Refreshes and formats each pivot table in the workbook

4. Exports and saves specified sheets as a PDF document and saves the document name with the time stamp from step 2

5. Saves the workbook

6. Emails that specific PDF document just created as an email attachment in Excel.

7. Closes the Excel Application

I run this whole series in a private sub called Workbook_Open which checks to see if current time matches the specified runtime. If it does, it runs steps 1-7, if it is an hour later, it closes the workbook (that way I can work on it other than that two hour window).

Here is the code being used:
*Note, this code below is run in the "ThisWorkbook" Excel Object.

```
'This Macro will use check to see if you opened the workbook at a certain time, if you did, then it will run the Report Automation Macros below.

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

HourRightNow = Hour(Now())

If HourRightNow = 13 Then

Call RefreshDataTables
Call RefreshPivotTables
Call SaveWorkbook
Call ExportToPDFFile
Call EmailPDFAsAttachment
Call CloseWorkbook

ElseIf HourRightNow = 14 Then

Call CloseWorkbook

End If
    
End Sub


Sub RefreshDataTables()
'
' RefreshDataTables Macro
' This Macro is used to refresh the data from the Dentrix Tables.
'
'This selects the table and refreshes it.

Sheets("raw").Select
Range("D4").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Worksheets("NomenclatureVBA").Range("A2").Formula = "=now()"

End Sub


Sub RefreshPivotTables()
'
' RefreshPivotTables Macro
' This Macro refreshes each Pivot Table in the document.
'

'This goes through each sheet and refreshes each pivot table.
    Sheets("D0150 VS D0330 BY BIZLINE").PivotTables("D0150 vs D0330 by BIZLINE").PivotCache.Refresh
   
   Columns("B:DD").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With


    Sheets("D0150 VS D0330").PivotTables("D0150 COMP EXAM vs D0330 PANO").PivotCache.Refresh
    
    Columns("B:DD").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
'Formnats to the specific date format below.


    
    

    
End Sub

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sub SaveWorkbook()

' Saves Active (Open) Workbook

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub


'**********************READY************************
'More simplified and tested version of the Export To PDF format
'Make sure to update the filePaths, worksheets,

Sub ExportToPDFFile()
Dim strFilename As String


'Considering Sheet1 to be where you need to pick file name
strFilename = Worksheets("NomenclatureVBA").Range("C2")


Sheets(Array("D0150 VS D0330", "D0150 VS D0330 BY BIZLINE")).Select
Sheets("D0150 VS D0330").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "\\****(ServerNameGoesHere)****\UserFolders\_Common\DentrixEntrpriseCustomReports\Public\Owner Reports\DataAnalystAutomatedReports\Reports\D0150 COMP EXAM vs D0330 PANO\" & strFilename & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Sheets("NomenclatureVBA").Select

'This is where the exporting ends, now we will proceed to email the file.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

'The emailing begins here
'This says that if there is a file name stored in the strFileName variable, then....
End Sub



'This Macro Closes the workbook... Note that it closes the very specific workbook you choose.

Sub CloseWorkbook()

'Workbooks("Automated D0150 COMP EXAM vs D0330 PANO.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Then I also have the macro that emails the PDF file in the Modules section of VBA. It looks like this:

```
Sub EmailPDFAsAttachment()
' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010.
' This example sends the last saved version of the Activeworkbook object .
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim FilePath As String
    
    'This part is setting the strings and objects to be things. (e.g. FilePath is setting itself equal to the text where we plan to set up each report)
    
    FilePath = "\\***(ServerGoesHere)***\UserFolders\_Common\DentrixEntrpriseCustomReports\Public\Owner Reports\DataAnalystAutomatedReports\Reports\D0150 COMP EXAM vs D0330 PANO\" _
    & Worksheets("NomenclatureVBA").Range("C2") & ".pdf"
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
   ' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.
   '
   
    With OutMail
        .To = "email@example.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Worksheets("NomenclatureVBA").Range("C2")
        
        .HTMLBody = "Hello all!" & "<br>" & _
        "Here is this week's report for the Comp Exam vs. Pano." & "<br>" & _
         "Let me know what you think or any comments or questions you have!" & "<br>" & _
         vbNewLine & Signature & .HTMLBody
        
        .Attachments.Add FilePath
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the mail.
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

So this all runs fine when I open up the workbook at the 13th hour (1pm), however, when I try to run this in Task Scheduler during the 13th hour, it runs everything up until the EmailPDFAsAttachment macro/sub and it gets hung up somewhere in the macro and stops running.

I should also state that I have the Trust Center Settings to the following in both Outlook and Excel:
[TrustCenterSettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI9CA.png)

Anyone know whats causing the macro to run perfectly when I personally open the file and then when I try and open the file via Task Scheduler it stalls in the same spot?
**And anyone know how to make it run correctly via Task Scheduler?**

Comment: Try commenting out `On Error Resume Next`. Maybe you'll get a clue as to what error is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We realized that the server limited my permissions in the task scheduler. When I went my IT Director switched my permissions to Admin, it ran the task scheduler perfectly!

Sorry for the false alarm... I wouldn't have posted the question originally, but I spent all last week working on it. Thanks everybody for looking!

Answer (score -1):

That was my guess.  You have to mkae sure your password is entered correctly.  If you fat-finger a key and enter your password incorrectly, the Task Scheduler will accept it even though it shouldn't.  In my opionion, it should prompt the user and notify him/her of the error.  Maybe Microsoft will change this sometime in the near future.