# Windows Task Manager Schedule VBA Macro to Send An Email Using OutLook Daily Running Manually and Not Automatically

Tags: excel, email, macros, scheduled-tasks, vba

I have my macro which is running, & for this I created a vb script and used windows task manager to schedule its run every day.

Whenever I run manually or attempt changing the time in the trigger, I always make sure that both excel and outlook are not running.
If I run the macro in Excel VBA, it sends the email.
After scheduling the task to run everyday, just as a test if I go to (in TaskScheduler) View -> Hidden Tasks and manually click Run, it sends the email.

However, if I schedule it to run at a specific time everyday, say maybe starting today, 15 minutes from now, it does not send the email & the last run result is (0x0).

I have enabled all macros in the trust center settings and selected 'Trust access to the VBA project object model', & it's not an issue about administrator privileges. 
This is my VB script

```
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\myUser\MyLocation\MyFile.xlsm")
ObjExcel.Visible = False
ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
ObjExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
ObjExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

'vbs opens a file specified by the path below
'either use the Workbook Open event (if macros are enabled), or Application.Run

ObjExcel.Application.Run "MyFile.xlsm!main_macro"
ObjWB.Save
ObjWB.ActiveWorkbook.Close
ObjExcel.Quit

Set ObjWB = Nothing
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Also, here are my TaskScheduler Settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Ref:

[Sending email from excel automatically based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189863/sending-email-from-excel-automatically-based-on-date)

[How to set recurring schedule for xlsm file using Windows Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771185/how-to-set-recurring-schedule-for-xlsm-file-using-windows-task-scheduler/22789150#22789150)

[How can you run an Excel macro through a schedule task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914703/how-can-you-run-an-excel-macro-through-a-schedule-task/17632087#17632087)

[Task Scheduler does not run Excel VBA Code to send PDF as Email Attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555107/task-scheduler-does-not-run-excel-vba-code-to-send-pdf-as-email-attachment/37557589#37557589)

If I set the below to `True`:

```
ObjExcel.Visible = False
ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
ObjExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
ObjExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
```

Excel opens in read-only mode and says click notify to receive the notification that you can now edit the workbook but I cannot edit it, says another user has the workbook open for editing.

Comment: I assume, you are logged in, while the task is supposed to run, right?

Comment: Is there an open Excel-Process in the background?
Maybe your Script doesnt close your workbook cleanly.

Comment: I think the line "ObjWB.ActiveWorkbook.Close" should be "ObjWB.Close". ObjWB is already the workbook

Comment: If you run the script directly (the file, not the task), does there occur an error?

Comment: @JulianKuchlbauer thanks for all the help. The vbs scriot was throwing an error, "object not found", which I managed to resolve (and the email is sent). However, there is one remaining problem: I have 2 background excel processes still running for the 2 times that I was able to run the vbs script manually and run the scheduled task successfully. Any ideas?

Comment: so now the script runs without errors, but the excel processes dont quit?

Comment: @JulianKuchlbauer yes, precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the point is that the line

```
ObjWB.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

must be

```
ObjWB.Close
```

.

Please try this and comment your results.

Comment: There are still background excel processes running.

Comment: Yes it does, when I click on the vbs script manually. Using the task scheduler brings up the error: activex component can't create object

Comment: So the activex error comes up but the email is sent?

Comment: The very first time the email got sent (using task scheduler) and there were no errors. This time, using task scheduler, no email was sent and the error came up. I am using a 64-bit machine and this cscript C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe but I just discovered there is another one located here C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe  I just checked and the email won't send when I double click on the vb script now as well

Comment: What did you change in the script?

Comment: Just ObjWB.ActiveWorkbook.Close

Comment: so it suddenly doesnt work just by changing this line?

Comment: at that point in time yes, but now double clicking on the vbscript doesn't send the email (with no errors coming up) but using task scheduler does send the email with no errors.could it be something to do with this - I am using a 64-bit machine and this cscript C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe in task scheduler but I just discovered there is another one located here C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128230/discussion-between-julian-kuchlbauer-and-anon).